# grep lines NOT starting with # or empty lines

Tags: regex, unix, grep, regex-negation

When I use `grep` (GNU grep) 2.22 to print that do **not** start by `#` or that are **not** empty I need to do

`$ grep -v '^#' fileNameIGrepFor | grep -v '^$'`

I think this is ugly, is there a smarter way (using `grep` please)

Comment: Just use grep's "\|" operator to match `^#` or `^$`: grep -v "^#\|^$" filename

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
grep -v '^#' fileNameIGrepFor | grep -v '^$'
```

can be simplified into:

```
grep -v '^#\|^$' fileNameIGrepFor
```

To remove the ugly `\` you can use `grep -E`, or equivalently [`egrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/egrep):

```
egrep -v '^#|^$' fileNameIGrepFor
```

You could then clarify this a bit by grouping the terms:

```
egrep -v '^(#|$)' fileNameIGrepFor
```

And then make it a little more robust by including a check for whitespace before the `#`:

```
egrep -v '^(\s*#|$)' fileNameIGrepFor
```

Maybe you'll also want to exclude all blank lines (only contain whitespace)? In which case, again, the change is simple:

```
egrep -v '^\s*(#|$)' fileNameIGrepFor
```

Comment: In my case, I need to get the top-level elements in a YAML file. So that was also all lines not starting on a space. `grep -v '^#\|^$\|^ ' ./some.yaml`

Comment: @nelaaro As per my answer above, you can remove the ugly back-slashes with: `egrep -v '^(#|$| )'`

Comment: Or alternatively, you could check for lines that **do** start with a non-hash: `grep '^[^#]'`